# Getting the type of parameters in a parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

So let's say we have the following code:

```
#include <stack>

template<class... Args>
auto make_stack(Args&&... args)
{
    std::stack<INSERT_TYPE_HERE> s;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    auto s = make_stack(1, 2.2, 3); //would be std::stack<double>
    auto s2 = make_stack(1l, 2, 3); //would be std::stack<long>
}
```

How would I find the common type of the arguments in the parameter pack?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no guarantees that the types are the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) from `<type_traits>`. It is a type trait that provides the common type all types can be converted to. So in your case you'd need:

```
template<typename... Args>
auto make_stack(Args&&... args)
{
    using commonT = std::common_type_t<Args...>;
    std::stack<commonT> s;
    return s;
}
```

**EDIT** As @DietmarKühl mentioned in the comment, you may want to use a [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) on `commonT` if you use C++11 and not C++14. It looks like the `std::decay` is applied on the resulting type only since C++14.

Comment: Could you provide a short example of that?

Comment: @DeiDei In a sec... Done.

Comment: I _think_ you might want to `std::decay_t<....>` the result obtained from `std::common_type<...>`: if all elements are lvalue you'd otherwise try to create a `std::stack<...>` of references.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I think `std::common_type` does the decay, see e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type

Comment: @DietmarKühl I glanced over the std::common_type and I believe `std::decay` is only applied to the resulting type since C++14. My compiler seems to apply it to C++11 too, I wonder if this was considered as a defect in the C++11 standard.

Comment: Is it only decay, or actual conversion? If it's the latter, it seems like that's not exactly the answer to OP's question...

Comment: @einpoklum It is conversion, the decay comment was about removing cv-reference from the type.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are no guarantees that the types are the same.
You can use `std::common_type`, but be aware that (from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)):

> Determines the common type among all types T..., that is the type all T... can be implicitly converted to.

This means that it could be not the one that you expect it to be.

Anyway, by looking at your example, it looks to me that your problem can be easily solved by means of a templated function like the one below and the use of an `initializer_list`.
It follows a working example:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <stack>

template<typename T>
auto make_stack(std::initializer_list<T> list)
{
    std::stack<T> s;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    auto s = make_stack<double>({1, 2.2, 3}); //would be std::stack<double>
    auto s2 = make_stack<long int>({1l, 2, 3}); //would be std::stack<long>
}
```